# Using the JInput

Tags: java, jinput

I have done A LOT of researching but I can't seem to find a basic code for JInput that gets the X and Y axis of the controller. Also, to "select"/set your controller, how do you filter out the mouse and keyboard? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The getting started guide on the java gaming forums should have the information you need.

[JInput forums home](http://www.java-gaming.org/boards/jinput/27/view.html)